# Where are the conda dependency conflicts in this output? I can't see them. :(

Tags: python, dependencies, anaconda, conda

I'm getting the following output when attempting to install a package from my own *Anaconda* channel:

```
(pybert-tst)
dbanas@Davids-MacBook-Pro:~/Documents/Projects/PyBERT
$ conda install -c dbanas pybert
WARNING conda.base.context:use_only_tar_bz2(632): Conda is constrained to only using the old .tar.bz2 file format because you have conda-build installed, and it is <3.18.3.  Update or remove conda-build to get smaller downloads and faster extractions.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

  - pybert -> chaco -> enable -> fonttools -> brotli -> libcxx[version='>=4.0.1'] -> libcxxabi==4.0.1=hcfea43d_1
  - pybert -> chaco -> enable -> fonttools -> munkres -> python -> libffi[version='>=3.2.1,<4.0a0']
  - pybert -> chaco -> enable -> fonttools -> munkres -> python -> ncurses[version='>=6.1,<7.0a0']
  - pybert -> chaco -> enable -> fonttools -> munkres -> python -> readline[version='>=7.0,<8.0a0']
  - pybert -> chaco -> enable -> fonttools -> munkres -> python -> sqlite[version='>=3.27.2,<4.0a0'] -> libedit[version='>=3.1.20181209,<3.2.0a0']
  - pybert -> chaco -> enable -> fonttools -> munkres -> python -> sqlite[version='>=3.27.2,<4.0a0'] -> zlib[version='>=1.2.11,<1.3.0a0']
  - pybert -> chaco -> enable -> fonttools -> munkres -> python -> tk[version='>=8.6.8,<8.7.0a0']
  - pybert -> chaco -> enable -> fonttools -> munkres -> python -> xz[version='>=5.2.4,<6.0a0']
  - pybert -> chaco -> enable -> fonttools -> unicodedata2
  - pybert -> chaco -> enable -> numpy
  - pybert -> chaco -> enable -> pillow -> freetype[version='>=2.9.1,<3.0a0'] -> libpng[version='>=1.6.34,<1.7.0a0']
  - pybert -> chaco -> enable -> pillow -> jpeg[version='>=9b,<10a']
  - pybert -> chaco -> enable -> pillow -> libtiff[version='>=4.0.10,<5.0a0'] -> zstd[version='>=1.3.7,<1.3.8.0a0'] -> lz4 -> lz4-c[version='>=1.8.1.2,<1.9.0a0']
  - pybert -> chaco -> enable -> pillow -> libtiff[version='>=4.0.10,<5.0a0'] -> zstd[version='>=1.3.7,<1.3.8.0a0'] -> lz4 -> setuptools -> certifi[version='>=2016.09']
  - pybert -> chaco -> enable -> pillow -> olefile
  - pybert -> chaco -> enable -> pyface -> pygments
  - pybert -> chaco -> enable -> pyface -> pyqt -> dbus[version='>=1.13.2,<2.0a0'] -> expat[version='>=2.2.6,<3.0a0']
  - pybert -> chaco -> enable -> pyface -> pyqt -> dbus[version='>=1.13.2,<2.0a0'] -> glib[version='>=2.56.2,<2.57.0a0'] -> gettext[version='>=0.19.8.1,<1.0a0'] -> libiconv[version='>=1.15,<2.0a0']
  - pybert -> chaco -> enable -> pyface -> pyqt -> dbus[version='>=1.13.2,<2.0a0'] -> glib[version='>=2.56.2,<2.57.0a0'] -> pcre[version='>=8.42,<9.0a0']
  - pybert -> chaco -> enable -> pyface -> pyqt -> qt[version='5.9.*,>=5.9.6,<5.10.0a0'] -> icu[version='>=58.2,<59.0a0']
  - pybert -> chaco -> enable -> pyface -> pyqt -> sip[version='>=4.19.4,<=4.19.8']
  - pybert -> chaco -> enable -> pyface -> traits
  - pybert -> chaco -> enable -> pyparsing
  - pybert -> chaco -> enable -> six
  - pybert -> chaco -> enable -> traitsui
  - pybert -> docutils
  - pybert -> jinja2
  - pybert -> kiwisolver
  - pybert -> pyibis-ami[version='>=3.0.0'] -> scipy
  - pybert -> scikit-rf
  - pybert -> sphinx
```

And I don't understand what I'm being told, because I don't see any actual *conflicts* reported.
For instance, the first spec. calls for package `libcxx` to be ">=4.0.1".
But, I don't see package `libcxx` mentioned in any of the other specs.
So, where's the conflict?

Can someone help me understand where the incompatibilities are in the above output?

Comment: I've been observing changed behavior of conda since about two weeks ago, and there have been other questions on SO where the conda output didn't really indicate a conflict. I think there might be a bug in conda that lets it omit something relevant from the output. Have you checked the conda issue tracker, or considered to open an issue yourself? https://github.com/conda/conda/issues

Comment: Aha! You're right: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8863
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As per Roland Weber's hint, this was due to an unstable `conda` released (I think) just before the end of June.